# Crawl user articles from social network programmatically

Tags: facebook, web-crawler, social-networking, web

Is it possible to crawl user information programmingly from social network like Facebook?
I need some user information(more specifically, the articles posted) to do a small data mining project.

I think I have the following questions.

1. Is it a must to login(Let's say Facebook) in order to retrieve information, if I do not have direct access to the database.(So I have to crawl it)
2. If it is a must, how can I log into my account(like Facebook) in a programmingly way?
3. Is their any articles repository available? The more data, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has an API that will allow you to access this information. An API provides a developer with an interface to access Facebook data and even perform operations. You should subscribe your application and you will get a key to use the API.

If a Facebook user has some information available publicly you can access it without requesting access, otherwise you will need the user to accept your application for you to use his private information.

Here is the main link for any development using Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/

And here is the main link to the API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

And this getting started should be useful:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/